# Responsivity of menu

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive-design

I am building a website based on wordpress theme which should be responsive. But if I resize the browser window and make it smaller, the menu just hides somewhere under the header. Is there anyone capable of fixing that?

[The Website](http://svycarsky-dum-responsive.geneweb.cz/)

Comment: remove the `position: absolute !important;` from `.assistive-text` and it will show up again.

Comment: [link](http://gyazo.com/d11d19b40154be2a295fc159f02e8ce6) this is what happened @DominikAngerer

Comment: Of course you need to add this only for a specific sie using media query :)

Comment: You mean the position: `absolute !important;` line? @DominikAngerer

Comment: use media query + `position:static`which is the default value - so you can set it back to non absolute for smaller devices :)

Comment: I now had a deeper look at you DOM. I would say that you should create another menu structure for the mobile part - which is display:none for desktop and display:block for mobile (which at first is only a symbol) and on click on that symbol you would add height to the new menu which then lays over the screen (you can absolute position that directly under the main header)

Answer (score 0):

you can use bootstrap framework for responsive theme 
work with bootstrap is easy
[bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/)